# &#34; changes to double quotation mark

Tags: javascript

My problem right now is that i have a piece of text in a function call inside an onClick.
I can swear that the double quotation mark is encoded to `&#34;` but the whole thing just breaks down because it changes somehow back to a normal double quotation mark.

```
usShow("LCD TV 0-23" SONY");
```

I have to add that it is all built dynamically in JS.

Does JS changes encoded characters to their original form on the fly, or there is something I've never understood about coding?

Answer (score 2):

```
usShow("LCD TV 0-23\" SONY");
```

Simple, huh? There's even another solution:

```
usShow('LCD TV 0-23" SONY');
```

Comment: my problem is that the data is not consistent. sometimes I hit 23" and sometimes 23'

Comment: but why &amp;#34; keeps on changing to "?

Comment: `&#34;` is handled at the HTML level. Basically, the browser converts such entities BEFORE parsing the JavaScript code. Like I said and like Spencer Ruport also said, you should escape your quotes with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

How is that line of code generated? I know in ASP.Net there were (are?) certain output functions which (incorrectly) decode HTML encoded characters. If you're having trouble, try outputting the following instead:

```
usShow("LCD TV 0-23\" SONY");
```

That should be easier to output.